# typeahead results are not consistently returned at the same quantity

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I'm trying to debug why my twitter typeahead results are not consistent, and I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what's going wrong.  Even though the page I query that provides data to typeahead is returning 50 results each time, sometimes typeahead gives me 2, or 15, or all 50 in my dropdown, and I don't know what is causing this discrepancy.

```
/* Bloodhound  */
partsList = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {                                                                                                                                         
      url: 'search.php?p=%QUERY',                
      wildcard: '%QUERY',
      minLength: 1,
      filter: function (partsList) {        
        return $.map(partsList, function (itemNumber) {
          console.log(itemNumber.one);                           
          return {
            itemOneHeader   : itemNumber.header_one,
            itemTwoHeader   : itemNumber.header_two,                 
            itemOne         : itemNumber.one,
            itemTwo         : itemNumber.two,                                           
          };                                
        });
      }
    },
    limit: 49
});


/* Main search box typeahead */
$('.mainSearchBox').typeahead(
{   hint: false,
    name: 'mainSearchBox',
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
},
{
    displayKey: 'itemOne',    
    templates: {       
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile( settings == "a" ? "<strong>{{itemOne}}</strong>" : "<div><strong>{{itemOne}}</strong> <div class='suggestion'>{{itemTwo}}</div></div>" )
    },    
    source: partsList.ttAdapter(),
    limit: 49
})
.on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {    
      iOne           = datum.itemOne;
      iTwo           = datum.itemTwo;
      iOne_header    = datum.itemOneHeader;                  
      iTwo_header    = datum.itemTwoHeader;      
      headerOne      = iOne_header;
      headerTwo      = iTwo_header;               

})
.on('typeahead:asyncrequest', function() {
    $('#loadingCogs').html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-3x fa-spin"></i>');
})
.on('typeahead:asynccancel typeahead:asyncreceive', function() {
    $('#loadingCogs').html('');
});
```

If I look at the `console.log(itemNumber.one)` line, here's what prints out to my console:

```
BAS
BAS01
BAS0234
BAS2349
BAS29939
BAS52
BAS11
BAS69
BAS67
BAS24
84BAS92
92BAS
BAS9
9600BAS
BAS22,74
86BAS
87BAS
88BAS
89BAS
90BAS
```

But in the typeahead window, all I see is:

```
BAS
BAS01
```

This is completely not consistent however - if I do another search, for `BA` - I get about 50 results, and typeahead shows all 50.  Searching for `ASDF` gives me 32 results, all 32 I see - there seems to just be certain search terms that cause me to only get back a few results.

I'm not sure whether or not there is data that is being returned that causes typeahead to stop functioning when it hits that data, error out, and only return 2 or 3 results, but it's definitely not just the literal search term `BA` that is giving me back "bad" results - I cannot find any pattern to why it returns good vs. bad results...

In the complete search term BAS04052 I get back the following data:

```
Term    console.log    typeahead
B           50            50
BA          50             3
BAS         48            48
BAS0        46            46
BAS04       41            41
BAS040      32            18
BAS0405     16            16
BAS04052    15            15
```

Comment: What does your `partList` object look like when using it in `typehead`? Since `bloodhound` is running asynchronously I suspect what may be happening is certain queries take longer to respond, and response time depends on your connection, so that could be what causes the inconsistency. However, I am not familiar with `typehead` or `bloodhound` so just speculation from the code you have provided.